# ORACLE: How to combine UNIQUE Constraint with other column?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, unique-constraint

I'm trying to solve the below problem by adding unique constraint combining with another column.

My table:

```
Value    Flag
1        Y
2        Y
3        Y
1        N
2        N
3        N
```

Neither of them are primary key.

I can't have duplicate values for the given flag, i.e., For flag 'Y', I can't have duplicate values. Same goes for flag 'N'.

```
Value    Flag
1        Y
2        Y
3        Y
3        Y        <--- This should not be allowed
```

I'm trying to add a constraint for this condition as below.

```
  ALTER TABLE Table_name 
  ADD CONSTRAINT Value_constraint
  CHECK ((UPPER(Flag) = 'Y' AND UNIQUE(Value)) OR
         (UPPER(Flag) = 'N' AND UNIQUE(Value)));
```

But I'm getting the error message

```
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the combination is not allowed, then add a unique constraint or index:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name 
  ADD CONSTRAINT Value_constraint UNIQUE (Value, Flag);
```

If you always want the flag to be upper case, then add a constraint to that effect as well:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name 
  ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Flag_Upper CHECK (Flag = UPPER(Flag));
```